# Why does Create Tweet function don't work when added

Tags: twitter, angular12

createTweet don't work from angular, I see in chrome -> elements that the script added after 3 sec, if I copy the script that added from the HTML that rendered and run it in console it's working,
so why the twit not showing?

> also the result from create twit function is

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
```

> footer script in index.html

```
<script>
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>

<div id="scripts-footer"></div>
```

code in component

```
const element = document.getElementById('scripts-footer');
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  var code = ` setTimeout(() => {
               twttr.widgets.createTweet('1422119154639949826',document.getElementById('mytwit'));   
               }, 3000);
     `;
  script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  element?.parentNode?.insertBefore(script, element);
```

> HTML in component

```
<div id="mytwit"  ></div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: the question is why the twit not showing even that i see that the script runing in chrome